# Asymptotic variance of GMM with efficient instrument

Tags: econometrics, asymptotics, generalized-moments, efficiency

This question emerged from reading [Wooldridge's Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, second edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262232588), section 14.4.3, where the asymptotic distribution of the GMM (Generalized Method of Moment) estimator with efficient instruments is derived.

I have an issue which looks like a simple algebra problem, but for some reason I am missing something and I am not able to solve it. Sorry in advance : it takes a bit of notation and derivation to explain the issue at stake with enough clarity.

We have a moment condition

$$E(r(w_i, \theta_0) | x_i ) = 0,$$

from which we derive

$$ E ( Z(x_i) r(w_i, \theta_0) | x_i ) = 0,$$

for any $Z$ function of $x_i$ only. Then by the LIE we have the unconditional moment condition

$$ E ( Z(x_i) r(w_i, \theta_0) ) = 0,$$

from which we can derive the GMM estimator $\hat{\theta}_Z$ . Wooldridge tells us that the most efficient choice for $Z$ is

$$ Z^*(x_i) \equiv \big[\underbrace{Var\big(r(w_i,\theta_0 | x_i)\big)}_{\equiv \Omega_0(x_i)}\big]^{-1} \underbrace{E(\nabla_{\theta} r(w_i,\theta_0) | x_i)}_{\equiv R_0(x_i)}$$

and then derives the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}_{Z^*}$

$$ \sqrt{N} (\hat{\theta}_{Z^*} - \theta_0) \rightarrow^d N ( 0, [G_0 \Lambda_0^{-1} G_0 ]^{-1}),$$

where

$$G_0 \equiv E\big(R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i) \big) $$

and

$$\Lambda_0 =  E\big(R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i) \big).$$

Now my problem is with the next claim

$$ E\big(R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i) \big) = E\big(R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i) \big),$$

which in turn implies that $G_0 = \Lambda_0$.

For the last claim to work, we seem to need

$$ r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)' = \Omega_0 (x_i).      (1)$$

I understand that because $ E ( r(w_i, \theta_0)|x_i ) = 0$, we have $E[r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)'|x_i] = \Omega_0$, but I do not see how this leads to (1). Or is it something completely different? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Law of Iterated Expectations (careful with parentheses)

$$\Lambda_0 =  E\big[R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i) \big] $$

$$=E\Big(E\big[R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i)\mid x_i \big] \Big)$$

Then "take out what's known"

$$=E\Big(R_0 (x_i)' \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) \cdot E\big[r(w_i, \theta_0)r(w_i, \theta_0)' \mid x_i \big]\cdot \Omega_0^{-1}(x_i) R_0 (x_i)\Big)$$

and since as you too write,
$$ \Omega_0 =  E\Big[r(w_i,\theta_0 )r(w_i,\theta_0 )'\mid x_i\Big]$$

substitute to get the result.

Comment: Use the LIE, as usual uh...;) Many thanks @AlecosPapadopoulus.

Comment: Yeah, it is almost like a magic wand.